# how to use for loop in xml response

Tags: android

thi is my code which work fine in blackberry and get 3 responses which show in textview but wheni use this code in android is just show values only 1 times not 3
so how i use 1  text view to print 3 times result??

```
  for (int x = 7; x <= xmlRespone.length - 1; x = x + 3) {

                    TextView lblTransactionDate = 
  (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.lblTransactionDate);
                    lblTransactionDate.setText("Transaction   
 Date : "+ xmlRespone[x][1]);              





     lblTransactionDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor
  (R.color.text_color_slateblue));

                    TextView lblAmount = (TextView)   
      findViewById(R.id.lblAmount);
                    lblAmount.setText("Amount : " +    
      xmlRespone[x + 1][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

see [TextView.append(CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for showing all Values in Single TextView.Change your code as:

```
    TextView lblTransactionDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTransactionDate);

    TextView lblAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblAmount);

    for (int x = 7; x <= xmlRespone.length - 1; x = x + 3) {
// if you want to clear Prev value
    lblTransactionDate.setText(""); 
    lblTransactionDate.setText("Transaction  Date : "+ xmlRespone[x][1]);        
    // if you want to append with Prev Value
    lblTransactionDate.append("Transaction  Date : "+ xmlRespone[x][1]);      

    lblTransactionDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_slateblue));

    // if you want to clear Prev value
    lblAmount.setText("Amount : " + xmlRespone[x + 1][1]);
    // if you want to append with Prev Value
    lblAmount.append("Amount : " +  xmlRespone[x + 1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Um... the textview will take all three values, but only the last one will remain shown. If you want to append text to it, do

```
text.setText(text.getText() + "new_text");
```

Or you could just use

```
text.append("new_text");
```

But maybe youjust want to post a 'notification' like message to your user, for which Toast is used for like this

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Signing in with default user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Just be sure to call the Toast from the UI thread, if not use this

```
public void fireToast(final String toast)
{
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use Toast.makeText(context, "The text you want to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); instead of a textview, or use textview's append() instead of setText()...